# Show SSIS Data Flow OnProgress events

Tags: sql-server, events, ssis

I have a C# windows form .exe that loads and executes an SSIS package when a button is pressed.

To show progress to the user, it has an event handler in it.

```
    class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
{
    public Label MyLabel;
    public override void OnProgress(TaskHost taskHost, string progressDescription,
        int percentComplete, int progressCountLow, int progressCountHigh, string subComponent, ref bool fireAgain)
    {
        MyLabel.Text = progressDescription;
        return;
    }
}



   //in the userform button onclick:
   MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();
   eventListener.MyLabel = label2;
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
   Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener);
   DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);
```

It works, but there's a problem. Only the Validation and Execute SQL Script tasks show the OnProgress message. I also have many Data Flow tasks, and I want them to also show their default message, like "Doing Data Flow Task 35" or whatever. What's the simplest way I can do that?

Note that I haven't configured anything regarding events in SSIS, so all these events are fired by SSIS on its own.

Note 2: I'm hoping that's there's just a checkbox somewhere I can tick. I really don't want to have to manually create Script tasks to explicilty call the events after each Data Flow, that's crazy.

Note 3: I'm not interested in saving the events anywhere, just briefly showing them in the form label.

Comment: You can try to activate a **Verbose** logging for the run-time execution. it is most chatty from the generated events perspective.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Do you know how I can do that? I edit my package.dstx in Visual Studio with SSIS Extension. I havent found option that says "Verbose"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find what the [DefaultEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.defaultevents?view=sqlserver-2019) class correlates to, but if you're not seeing the Information events *i.e.* Doing Data Flow Task 35, then you should implement a handler for [OnInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtsevents.oninformation?view=sqlserver-2019)

And as I often advise people who are writing their own SSIS package runner, to make this work on a user desktop or a web interface, you'll need to have the SSIS assemblies installed on the target machine. Those assemblies are a licensed asset of SQL Server which means you need a Standard (~8k per core, minimum 4) or Enterprise (~22k per core, minimum 4) License to be in compliance with Microsoft. In the event of an audit, since those libraries aren't easily accidentally installed, the finger wag of non-compliance is much more likely to become the fist of punitive damages

Comment: Excellent, OnInfo has much better messages and pops often so the userform looks much more responsive now. As for the second thing, the exe was already here I'm just improving it.